# Get the Character position on a String

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to find the current location of a character in a String.

The character itself is a linefeed `\n`.

So far I've managed to detect if the string contains the specific char with the following code:

```
let till: Character = "\n"
if let idx = text.characters.index(of: till) {
    print("linefeed detected")
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

If I `print` the `idx` variable I get the following output:

`Index(_base: Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView.Index(_position: 35), _countUTF16: 1)`

As you can see, if gives the position, which in this case is `35`

My question is, How can I access that position instance number?
How can I know if the position is X, Y or Z.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should try this:

**Swift 3**

```
let till: Character = "\n"
    if let idx = text.characters.index(of: till)
    {
        let pos = text.characters.distance(from: text.startIndex, to: idx)
        print(pos)
    }
    else
    {
        print("not found")
    }
```

Comment: ahhh... I never remembered the distance option :D
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distance` method to get index of character that you looking for.

```
extension String {
    func indexOf(string: String) -> Int? {
        if let indexOfCharacter = characters.index(of: Character(string)) {
            let distance = characters.distance(from: startIndex, to: indexOfCharacter)
            return distance
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you. The above answer refers to the same. I completely forgot the distance method

Answer (score -1):

// i hope it will help you

```
let NotFound = -1

extension String {
public func index(of charecter: Character) -> Int {
    if let index = characters.index(of: charecter) {
        return characters.distance(from: startIndex, to: index)
    }
    return NotFound
 }
}
```

Comment: hello please give me the reason why you down voted for this answer.